# jQuerys index() function returns object instead of int

Tags: jquery

In my Script, I have an jQuery onmouseover() bound to list items with a div as parent.
Now when I move the mouse over the li items, I want to get the index of this item in relation to its parent element (div).

so i use

```
var index = $($(this).index());
```

to get the hovered elements index as integer.
The jquery documentation says

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

but the index var is an object. If I try to alert it (instead of using console.log for basic debugging), the dialogs' content is "[object object]".

Can you help me? Why is my code block returning an object although the documentation says it would return an integer when called without arguments?

Comment: Why did you wrap the code into another $(...)?

Comment: As @AurelioDeRosa suggests, just use `var index = $(this).index()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you have to do is get rid of the additional `$(...)`. The code should be this:

```
var index = $(this).index();
```

Comment: Thanks. When I review my Code block I simply don't understand why I wrapped it in an additional object block…